# Create library with components with custom UI

Tags: android, events, touch-event

Now this might be a tricky one :)
The thing is that I whould like to create a library of all my custom components (such as custom buttons, seekbars.. etc etc) for an easier way to implement them in the future..
But the thing is that I have this round button.. which for now extends from the "ImageButton-widget"
Once the button is pressed I use the onTouched-listener to determine if the user actually pressed the round button, and not outside of it..since the ImageButton-widget is "treated" as a "square"..now so far no problems..
But what if I now want to reuse this button but also want to do something else within the onTouched-event, for instance call another method?.. I cant use just the onPressed-listener since that whould also be "triggered" even if the user doesnt press the round button (the upper and lower corners of the imagebutton will trigger onPressed aswell)

So.. is there anyway to without having to touch my code for the actual roundbutton-class to trigger the onTouched-event but run some more code?..

To put it all simple.. can I have two onTouched events for the same object and then decide which order they should "trigger in"..

Sorry this might be kind of confusing.. but I hate to rewrite my code over and over..

Thanks in advance!